# Accessing elements of an object in a jList/listModel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist

I'm trying to populate a jList, I want it to display a name but also store an ID (which is not displayed) for each item in the list.

I have created a list model and added each element as an object. The object holds an int value (the ID) and a string value (the name):

```
doorListModel.addElement(nextDoor);
```

Once all the elements have been added I then send this model to the jList:

```
jList1.setModel(doorListModel);
```

When you run the program the jList appears to just show a memory location for each element:
[image: Current jList output]

How can I get the jList to just display the String value and, (assuming this is possible) how do I access the hidden int value if I was to select an item from the jList.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two options as I see it:

- You can give your Door class a decent `toString()` method since this is what the JList displays by default, or
- Give your JList a decent ListCellRenderer. This is the recommended solution since a `toString()` result really shouldn't be used for production purposes but rather for debugging.

Comment: If you use the renderer approach then don't forget to override the `getNextMatch(...)` method of the JList since this method uses the toString() implementation of the object in the model to do a search of the items in the list. If you don't override this method you will break the default functionality of the JList.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate about how to use ListCellRenderers, I found the following but I don't understand it at all:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/342147/GUI/java/understanding-custom-ListCellRenderers

Comment: @Suipaste: Use of a ListCellRenderer is well described in the [JList Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). I suggest that you give it a look and then give it a try. If still stuck, please ask a more specific question then the one above which is nearly impossible to answer without re-writing a complete tutorial. Remember, the more specific your question, usually the more specific and helpful the answer.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to override toString (as a "solution" with equal weight as the renderer approach). That's simply wrong in anything but the most trivial uis, and you _know_ it :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: I've not given them equal weight -- please read my 2nd bullet which states `"this is the recommended solution..."`

Comment: @kleopatra: Come on now. The OP at least did, and is asking about how to use ListCellRenderer in his comment above yours. Regardless, the indication for your down-vote is not true as whether you've read it correctly or not, they've not been given equal weight.